# NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Buen día!

Tengo una app que me pasaron desarrollada para ios, tengo nulos conocimientos en swift, cocoa y demás. Al tratar de correr la app me marca el siguiente error:

```
2018-05-28 10:22:09.264671-0500 GP[1557:49855] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010497e1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103bcc031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049f3975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001035e9a68 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:] + 129
    4   GP                                  0x000000010329b22f +[JsonReader createFromJson:] + 159
    5   GP                                  0x0000000103291554 -[UIMapViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 484
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001059fe626 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 295
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001059fe4f9 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000105a0377e -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4505
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000105a09558 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 364
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010500a808 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ad0d61a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ad1182b _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ac9829f _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010acc5940 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104f3534f _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 167
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010589a532 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6875
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104920bb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049054af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104904a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010490430b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b5f9a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000104f3b0b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  GP                                  0x000000010329af0f main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108517955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Podría alguien orientarme a resolver esta situación gracias

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada te recomendaría hacer un breve repaso de Swift si te vas a poner a trabajar con él. Segundo, estaría bien que debugeases para saber exactamente donde te lanza este error y en su defecto publicar el código para poder facilitarnos a la comunidad más información para poder responderte.

En tu caso, estás asignando (no sé donde porque no veo el código) a algo un valor que es nulo. (Fijate en el reason).

Comment: Eso es lo interesante, el tiempo no es suficiente para dar un repaso de swift, que parte de código debo agregar para que pueda saber donde esta el error, marca en varios archivos el debug para no agregar código innecesario. Podrías orientarme?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que leí en el error `NSConcreteMutableString` se intento iniciar con una string nula, (`nil`). Esto podría porque dicha string no fue inicializada o se le asigno el valor `nil`.

Para poder debuguear este error, yo pondría un `Breakpoint` para `All Exceptions`. Este breakpoint parará el programa cuando se genere una excepción como la que te sucedió.

Para agregar este, realiza los siguientes pasos:

1. Ve a la pestaña de `Breakpoint Navigator`
2. Haz click en el simbolo de `+`, en la esquina inferior izquierda.
3. Selecciona `Exception Breakpoint`

Te adjunto una imagen con los pasos mencionados anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]